# I'm trying to use google maps and need to get natural feature like ocean, sea etc

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use google maps and need to get natural feature like ocean, sea, etc. All i need is just names but all i get is ZERO_RESULTS. My request is like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=0,0&sensor=true_or_false . Is it possible to get natural features with lat/lon ? Please turn me in right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) with type

```
var request = {
    location : {
        lat : 0,
        lng : 0
    },
    radius : radius,
    types: ['natural_feature']
};
```

Comment: can you speak android?

Comment: Note: The types below are not supported in the types filter of a place search, or in the types property when adding a place.    natural_feature